# How to restrict access to CometD clients to certain Platform Events?

Tags: platform-event, cometd, accesstoken

I need to publish multiple events, with different clients subscribing to different type of events. Is there a way to implement policies / permissions to different Channels? So I can restrict clients to access only some channels

Comment: Did you try using streaming channel? Channel allows particular events only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to identify the user through his profile or the user id and then publish your event. Basically you should have a some criteria to identify the channel before even publishing. Once published it just broadcasts to the receivers.